# cordova ios 6.0.0 not showing splash screen images

Tags: cordova, wkwebview, splash-screen, cordova-ios

I created a new project using cordova ios 6.0.0.

I added folders with the splash screen images, I am using launch storyboard images, and added them to the config.xml:

```
<splash src="res/screen/ios/Default@2x~universal~anyany.png" />
<splash src="res/screen/ios/Default@2x~universal~comany.png" />
<splash src="res/screen/ios/Default@2x~universal~comcom.png" />
<splash src="res/screen/ios/Default@3x~universal~anyany.png" />
<splash src="res/screen/ios/Default@3x~universal~anycom.png" />
<splash src="res/screen/ios/Default@3x~universal~comany.png" />
```

I have not customized the app any further. No plugins, nothing. And the splash screens don't show.

I see a totally blank, white screen, until the cordova deviceready page shows.

I read that you don't need splashscreen plugin with this version of cordova-ios. I tried adding it anyway, since splash screens did not show, but it was not added into iOS because it is for versions older than 6.

I added the preference AutoHideSplashScreen with a value of false to the config.xml, and set a timeout at index.js to hide the splash screen later. The only difference it made is that I see a white screen for longer than before.

I tried removing the ios platform and adding it back, no difference.

When I open the workspace in XCode, I see the splash screens are there under icons and splash screens.

Splash screens showed ok with cordova ios 5.1.1 on other apps, but this is a new app and I want to directly use cordova ios 6.0.0 .

Thanks for any help to get this resolved!

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone has the same issue, I resolved this by erasing the simulator content.

Simulator > Hardware > Erase all content and settings

Then when I run the app in it again, it showed the splash screen ok.

Comment: Cordova ios@6.0.0 had some issues. There is an update for it: Cordova ios@6.1.0  https://cordova.apache.org/blog/